# On a off topic question, is it ok to pitch in my 2 cents before voting to close?

Tags: discussion, comments, closed-questions

Sometimes I see beginners' questions which aren't adequate for the site at all. They have been downvoted and voted to close, but no comments have been left.

Is it doing a disservice if I offer a quick opinion ... the kind of thing you're not supposed to be fishing for? I voted to close since I'm on board with the moderation, but I like to pipe my opinions nonetheless. This isn't something particularly controversial either, the question is basically "what kind of cheap laptop do I need to do web dev". I was just going to recommend buying a windows machine and installing linux.